# Can a kitsune get a magical tattoo while in fox shape and use it in fox shape?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, polymorph

A kitsune caster with the feat [Fox Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/fox-shape/) wants to cast spells in fox shape. The [*caster's tattoo*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/tattoo-caster-s/) is a magic item that can be used once per day to cast a spell as if using the feats Silent Spell and Still Spell but without an increase in casting time or spell level. The problem is this kind of magic item usually becomes unusable when the possessor's form is changed into something other than a humanoid or monstrous humanoid.

If the magical tattoo is inscribed on the kitsune while the kitsune is in fox shape, would the magical tattoo be usable when the kitsune's in fox shape?

Comment: @FlashRebel may I ask if this is an existing character or one still being planned on? If the later, what class would that be?

Answer (score 1):

### Polymorphed creatures cannot activate any magic items

The rules on [polymorph](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation) are *very* restrictive on magic item activation, this clause is not simply talking about your melded gear, but any activation magic item cannot be used on your form:

> Items that require activation cannot be used while you maintain that form.

For instance, if you equipped the fox with tiny boots of speed, she could not activate them.

Even if the caster could activate the [Caster's Tattoo](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/tattoo-caster-s/), she could not cast while in the fox shape, as animals are not normally capable of spellcasting on their natural form as they lack ways to provide *verbal*, *somatic* and *material* components for spells. The first two are covered by the tattoo's magical effect:

> A caster’s tattoo is infused with potential magical energy that aids in casting spells that normally utilize verbal and somatic components. Once per day, a spellcaster may activate her caster’s tattoo as a swift action to automatically enhance **the next spell she casts in that round** with both the Still Spell and Silent Spell feats.

You still require some form to remove **material components** while [polymorphed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation), like using the [Eschew Materials](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eschew-materials-final), which would allow you to **cast any spell** without an expensive material focus, as you are removing *verbal*, *somatic* and *material* components (or most spells).

Of course, im disregarding spells that lack some or all of those requirements, as they could be cast without special abilities that remove them.

It might not be possible to create this [magical item](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/item-creation-feats/inscribe-magical-tattoo-item-creation) on a kitsune turned into a fox, as the [Fox Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/fox-shape/) ability works as [Beast Shape II](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape), which lasts only 1 minute/level. You would have to shape in and out of this form all day for several days (minimum 3) before the tattoo is finished. But that is *likely* a memory lapse from the author of the feat, as Fox Shape is supposed to enhance your natural ability to change shape according to it's flavor. So you will see table variation here (ask your GM).

> You can create magical tattoos, magic items inked directly into the flesh of a willing or helpless creature. Both you and the recipient of the tattoo (if the recipient is not yourself) **must be present during the entire tattooing process**.

Instead of a tattoo, you could also consider a [Ring of Eloquence](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-eloquence/), which allows you to [speak while on your fox form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jofNR_WkoCE) on four different languages. You still would require the [Still Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/still-spell-metamagic-final/) and [Eschew Materials](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eschew-materials-final) feats. That way, you will no longer be limited to a single spell per day and can cast any spells in your fox form. Though they use up slots 1 level higher if they have somatic components.

Comment: A fox-shaped kitsune does not equal a common fox, then "animals are not normally capable of spellcasting in their natural form" has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Being a parallel of the Kitsune's Change Shape racial ability, the duration would be up the the GM. I'd say it inherit's the racial's indefinite duration, although the feat doesn't specify that so your last point is valid RAW.

Comment: @FlashRebel that part is regarding what is described under polymorph rules. If this was a dragon form, for instance, my words would have been different.

Comment: I was pretty sure that the "animals are not normally capable of spellcasting" was a factor of the somatic requirement, and perhaps the intellect.  Certainly that's the case in 3.x - was it changed in Pathfinder?

Comment: @BenBarden the [polymorph rules in pathfinder](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation) state that your new form does not allow you to cast spells due to verbal, somatic and material components unless the new form is capable of spellcasting naturally and gives us as example, dragons.

Comment: There is no reason to think that the "items that require activation" clause applies to items that did not meld into your form.  The rules are also quite clear that the reason animals can't cast most spells is because they can't perform the components, which means that clause is irrelevant when there are no components to perform.

Comment: @darch as pointed on my answer, unless they have Eschew Materials, material components must still be suplied for the spells to be cast, the ability does not grant the caster the ability to ignore material components. I am talking about this bolded part of the spell entry: *"Components V, S, **M (a piece of the creature whose form you plan to assume)**"*

Comment: So... I think your post acknowledges this, but it does it in an awfully clumsy way.  Animals normally can't spellcast because spells normally require verbal, somatic, and material, and animals have problems with all three.  By implication, if the character themselves took Still Spell, Silent Spell, and Eschew Materials, they *could* cast in fox form (and taking only one or two of these would let them cast spells that did not require the others).

Comment: The original question, then, is whether there is any reasonable way to use the tattoo to get around the Still Spell and Silent Spell portions of that requirement, at least once per day

Comment: If that fits your understanding, I'd suggest that you clarify the appropriate pieces of the question - on first reading the answer makes it seem like the animal issue for spellcasting would not be solved by still/silent/eschew.  If it does not fit your understanding, I believe you are incorrect.

Comment: @BenBarden i thought that was implied on the question itself, since the objective of the caster tattoo is to gain the two feats required to remove verbal and somatic components.

Comment: I agree... but that means that you spend a lot of space (the paragraphs starting "Even if the caster" to "Of course I'm disregarding" inclusive) saying something that's pretty much implied int eh question itself already.  You could trim out a lot of that, and make for a better answer, I think.  Your pertinent points are "can't use items", "still have difficulty with material components", "arguably can't stay fox long enough to get the tattoo" and "perhaps try the ring?"

Comment: A lot of the stuff in the middle about verbal and somatic could (and probably should) be replaced by something like "Even if you could use it, it would only take care of verbal and somatic components, and then only once per day.  Animals also have difficulty with material components." or something similar.

Comment: Also, the ring thing probably doesn't work.  Foxes don't have a ring slot, so far as I'm aware.

Comment: @BenBarden the ring doesn't require activation, and it melds into your body. The ring *specific* rule states that it remains working regardless of your form.

Answer (score 0):

**Kitsune form cannot be changed**

It may be a *bit* rules-lawyery, but the rules text on [Fox Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/fox-shape/)
specifically state:

> You can take the form of a fox whose appearance is static and cannot
>   be changed each time you assume this form.

The tattoo would be a change in appearance of the fox shape, and is therefore forbidden.  Presumably, it would disappear after you reverted and changed over again.  On the bright side, it looks like your fox shape comes with an insta-groom feature.

Comment: I agree that there's a reading of that sentence that says, essentially, *The fox form's appearance is immutable, so, for instance, no matter how badly your fox form is mutilated nor how ingeniously the fox form is decorated, when the fox form is next assumed the fox form's appearance is unchanged.* However, I think the sentence is *really* there to prohibit fox shape from being used to assume the form of, for instance, a blue-furred or three-legged fox instead of the lone picked fox form. But I can totally see reading it the first way.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I acknowledge that your version of the sentence is the one that makes more intuitive sense, but when I give it a straight reading for what it actually says, "is static and cannot be changed" doesn't have a lot of space for exceptions.  Otherwise, you could do things like bleaching your fur, or giving yourself a trim, and thus changing the appearance.

Comment: That rule is *specifically* denying this part of the **polymorph rules**: *"Unless otherwise noted, polymorph spells cannot be used to change into specific individuals. Although **many of the fine details can be controlled**, your appearance is always that of a generic member of that creature’s type."*